# Service Pack 1 for Visual Studio 2010 wont install

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I was having some issues with this so I uninstalled **everything** associated with VS 2010 and .NET Framework 4 and reinstalled everything, well except Service Pack 1, which will not install. Without it installed I get this whenever I try to open Visual Studio 2010:

[image]

And this is the error I get when I try to install Service Pack 1

[image]

Can someone please help me with thnis issue?

Comment: Any chance to get a look at that log file mentioned in the dialog in that screenshot?

Comment: Working on it now, will post it once the install fails

Comment: This is what the log file shows: http://psychocoder.net/logfile.txt

Comment: Have you checked the answer given in [this question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/vssetup/thread/57de87cb-607f-4c49-baa3-128eb0fbebfd) yet? I think the error code `0x80070643` is the important bit of information.

Comment: Yes I checked it and it didn't offer any help

Answer (score 1):

According to the log file it is blowing attempting to patch the Team Foundation Server Object Model components.

from file:
Patch (L:\VS10sp1-KB983509.msp;L:\VS10sp1-KB2413561.msp;L:\VC10sp1-KB983509-x86.msp;L:\VC10sp1-KB983509-x64.msp;L:\VC10sp1-KB983509-IA64.msp;L:\VS10sp1-KB983509-Pro.msp) Install failed on product (Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Object Model - ENU).

If you are not using TFS, then you should be able to uninstall these from your computer via Add/Remove programs.  They should show up as 'Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Object Model -ENU'.  Once you have these uninstalled, perhaps you can try re-applying the service pack and again post the log file if it fails.

If they are not in your Add/Remove programs perhaps they did not properly get uninstalled previously?  You may need to use msizap to permanently remove any traces of them.

Comment: I did what you said and this time it made it 1/2 into the install before it started rollback. It was looking for ADONETEntityFrameworkTools_enu.msi and I directed to that file and it's still failing.

Comment: Please post the log again.  It will help identify what the install failure is and what component is the problem. It seems like you have a really botched install of Visual Studio.

Comment: My initial guess is that the 'Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools' are the problem component.  When you un-installed Visual Studio, did you also uninstall all of the other components it puts down, like the previously mentioned 'Microsoft ADO.NET Entity Framework Tools' and 'Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010 Object Model -ENU' re-installed Visual Studio 2010?  All of these get put down by the default install of Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes sir, when I uninstall I make sure to uninstall everything associated with VS 2010. Right now my latest attempt to install SP1 is failing, once it's complete I'll post the log file again

Comment: Here's the latest log file from the failed installation http://psychocoder.net/logfile2.txt

Comment: Your install is failing on the 'Visual Studio 2010 Prerequisites - English' -- this should be listed in Add/Remove programs.  What I would recommend that you do is the following:  See if you can uninstall the 'Visual Studio 2010 Prerequisites - English', if you can sucessfully install the component, then re-install it from the Visual Studio media (I am assuming you have either a disc or an ISO image).  The following url lists all of the components and how to perform an unattended install: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee225240.aspx

Comment: You do not need to perform an unattended install, but you can use the table to identify the correct MSI for the product in question.  You can also re-install the previously uninstalled TFS components if you so desire.

Comment: I dont see 'Visual Studio 2010 Prerequisites - English in Add/Remove programs though so how can I remove it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2387/discussion-between-art-and-psychocoder)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you got all the VS2010 products uninstalled? (For example, if you had express installed, then installed another version.)  In my list of installed apps I see three different items with "Visual Studio 2010" listed as part of their names.  I would try to uninstall all of them before re-installing and re-applying the service pack.

I don't suppose there was anything helpful in the log?

Comment: Nothing of use in the log. I uninstalled everything related to VS 2010 (never had Express installed) and .NET 4.0 and reinstalled, but nothing changes SP 1 just wont install

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything that was suggested here, and I thank everyone who took the time to try and help me. I ended up formatting my drive and re-installing Windows and all works now.